# Is there a way to save a screenshot of a page for legal purposes?

Tags: legal, screenshot

It could be an easy question, but it isn't.
If i create a screenshot using whatever tool it won't be legally useful, because screenshots are easily modified (through DOM manipulation or via photoshop).

My question is: Google cache or archive.org are tools that maybe could be recognized legally, but they create screenshots of the web randomly, is there a way to do this in a way that could represent a legal proof?

Thanks

Comment: Take a screenshot and mail it to yourself. Do not open. Save it.

Comment: clearly it isn't a good idea i believe.

Comment: Sure it is! This is how copyright is proven by law offices all the time.

Comment: How would this apply to a website you control?